# Adding/removing option from multiselect with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have jquery that will add an item to a select list and change the background color to indicate that it has been added (the select list is not visible). When I click the plus it adds the item to the list and changes the background to green. When I click it a second time it removes the item and color. This works once. If I repeat the cycle it stops working. Any ideas why that might be?

```
<ul>
<li><span id='add'> + </span>this is a test
 </li>
</ul>
<select multiple="multiple" id="destination"></select>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#add").click(function () {
var color = $("#add").css("background-color");
if (color == "transparent") {
  $("#add").css("background-color", "green");
  $("#destination").append('<option value="1">New option</option>');
} else {
  $("#add").css("background-color", "transparent");
  $("#destination option[value='1']").remove();
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the browser. In example in Chrome `$("#add").css("background-color")` returns `rgba(0,0,0,0)` not `transparent`. Thus reading a background color like this isn't cross-browser compliant.

In general I think you may be better off with classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/watRq/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#add").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("transparent")) {
      $(this).addClass("green").removeClass("transparent");
      $("#destination").append('<option value="1">New option</option>');
   } else {
      $("#add").addClass("transparent").removeClass("green");
      $("#destination option[value='1']").remove();
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't check for backgrounds, use just the [**`.toggle()` event**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

http://jsbin.com/unojap/4/edit

```
  $("#add").toggle(function () {

        $("#add").css("background-color", "green");
        $("#destination").append('<option value="1">New option</option>');

  },function(){
        $("#add").css("background-color", "transparent");
        $("#destination option[value='1']").remove();

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for background colors, use [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store whether an element has been added or not:

```
var added = $(this).data("added");
// returns undefined if requested data does not exist
if (!added) {
    $(this).data("added", true);
    // change background, do stuff
}
else {
    $(this).removeData("added");
    // change background, do stuff
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/DjWEn/)